# Bitcoin decompiler

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Is there any tool for Bitcoin blockchain decompiling?

I see news about [Ethereum Decompiler](https://www.coindesk.com/first-ethereum-decompiler-launches-jp-morgan-quorum-integration/), but is something like for Bitcoin?

Comment: If you got here like me looking for something to translate a script back into human readable tokens (more of a "disassembler" for the pedantic crowd), check out https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42576/online-bitcoin-script-simulator-or-debugger , especially https://github.com/kallewoof/btcdeb .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big different between the language used by the bitcoin blockchain and the one used in ethereum.

Ethereum smart contract programmers usually write their code in a high level language (such as solidity) and then compile it into hard to read bytecode.

Bitcoin script programmers write the code in a language that is not compiled, like if they were writing the bytecode itself (it isn't actually a bytecode though).

So it is logical that you can't decompile a language that was never compiled in the first place.

The thing you can do is look at the hexadecimal representations of bytes in a bitcoin script and check which operation they represent.

[This page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Words) has the list of all the commands and their hex value.

**Edit**

When you write a script in Bitcoin it is already fully transparent. It **never**  gets compiled, **NEVER**. It is already fully transparent because you **never** compile it. You don't need to decompile it because it was **never** compiled, just like you can't destroy an house that was never built in the first place.

Did I already mention that you don't need to decompile because the code **never gets compiled**?

Because it is really important to understand that it **never gets compiled**. You can just read it as it is.

If you see a `0x6a` in the code it reads like `OP_RETURN` as for the link i gave you above. You can read through the whole list of hex charachters in a script and decode it like that. There is nothing more you can do

I hope it will be clear now.

Comment: `So it is logical that you can't decompile a language that was never compiled in the first place.` Why you think so? It is impossible or impractical?

Comment: @Denis, compiling means converting source code into another, more basic (but less human-readable) code.  For example, converting C++ into x86 instructions.  Ethereum has it's own instruction set, but most people use a higher-level language and a compiler to convert it into the Ethereum instructions.  Bitcoin script is so simple and limited that nobody uses a higher level language.  As such, no compiler exists to convert this non-existent language into Bitcoin script, and no decomplier exists to convert it back.

Comment: @Denis how can you undo something that was never done?? It is not impossible or impratictical, it just never happened.

Comment: @IvanoDonadi I need full transparency for my tasks

Comment: @Denis you are just not getting it. Read my edit please and try to understand

Comment: I do not mean only the script, but I mean the structure of full database, all structure dependencies and trees of value flow and so on. The script here is a small part of question.

Comment: The link you posted about the ethereum decompiler is strictly about the script. Please read some basic documentation about bitcoin and the blockchain.

Comment: @IvanoDonadi thank you very much! •sarcasm•

Comment: I suggest that before using your wonderful sarcasm you read the wikipedia definition for decompiler:  **A decompiler is a computer program that takes an executable file as input, and attempts to create a high level source file which can be recompiled successfully. It is therefore the opposite of a compiler, which takes a source file and makes an executable.** and then read the article you posted as reference. **A decompiler is used on the code**

Comment: @IvanoDonadi I think there is language barier. I mean not fully what you answer me. But i accept your answer, thank you for help!